# CSS Limiting zoom?

Tags: html, css, wrapper, margin

My content wrapper will be centered in the body. the problem i have is that i have a certain div that will be partially reaching into the body and out of the wrapper using z-index. this works fine when using a certain solution. if an user is maximizing its desktop solution the frame of the content wrapper wont be visible anymore. even then the certain div is no more visible. so is there a way to limit the max. zoom?

here is an example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EKsyd/)

when you will zoom in you can see that the red div is from a certain point no more visible. this i would like to avoid if possible. thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you talking about zooming, or if the user re-sizes the width of their browser?

Comment: see the link and zoom in the page. you will see that the red div will be getting out of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various browsers allow you to define viewport metatags that define the allowable zoom limits (for example Web Kit-based browsers).  If you know what your target browsers are, you may want to investigate this.